# I tried using this Flag in setFlags from tutorial but its deprecated, what do i do

Tags: android, android-intent, android-developer-api

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET` is deprecated; so what should I use?

```
private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mforecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
    return shareIntent;


}
```

Comment: Consider using [ShareCompat.IntentBuilder](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/eEptYQgSaCf), which does much of this for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET):

> As of API 21 this performs identically to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT which should be used instead of this.

Since both symbols have the same numerical value (`0x00080000`), it does not really matter which one you use in terms of runtime behavior. If your `compileSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, switch to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT`

Answer (score 2):

See here ([Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html))

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
        }
```